# TCP and checksum

Tags: tcp, checksum

I write app for Android which will be communicate with HTTP server. I need to ensure that data will be provided to server without any changes. If any changes occured during the transmission I need to retransmit data. I know that TCP have it's own mechanism of checksum, and here is my question. Do I need to implement my own checksum system or maybe TCP checksum will enough?

Comment: Do you need to defend against man-made attacks, where data is sent from a rogue participant with correct check sum embedded in the packets?

Comment: Well these data is really sensitive data so I should secure it as much as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTTPS instead of HTTP. HTTPS adds a [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) to each record transferred, which guarantees data integrity. This protects against accidental damage during transmission, and also against tampering by an attacker.